# How can I ensure that the browser does not cache a page

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I need to make sure that the page is reloaded when going back to a page, without showing any messages to the user.

This must behave the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to achieve this reliably, especially with AJAX, is to append a query-string token on the page Url, such as `DateTime.Now.Ticks`.

You cannot count on `<META>` tags.

```
http://bla.com/bla.aspx?token=348343889
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT** - Added `SetNoStore()`

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I think you can do it this way too:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Here's a solution that's specific for Safari:

```
<body onunload="" ...>
```

Here's another solution, but it's a bit of a hack:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noBack(){window.history.forward();}
noBack();
window.onload=noBack;
window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack();}
window.onunload=function(){void(0);}
</script>
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Try the first solution again.

Comment: Posted a couple more solutions too.